About shared library export function use template class as return or pointer param when static CRT
a.dll
void a(std::string& str){
  str="123";
}

test.exe
int main(){
  std::string str;
  a(str);
}


If a.dll and test.exe is Static CRT linked, and assume that std::string handle a char* point cstr to the buffer.Since the two modules compile std::string separately. Is it right that a.dll uses its own crt to alloc memory for cstr . Then test.exe uses its own crt to free memory for cstr.
If 1 is true. Can it guarantee that it is correct when a.dll and test.exe linked with same version of crt.

//////////6.4 update
Assume std::string does not use Small String Optimization please . I want to get the code that follows a version of the c++ standard. Independent of the particular compiler and Windows version.
//////////

a gets a reference to a string passed. Why do you think a would allocate or deallocate a string?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai ...as part of the assignment str="123"; (under the hood)?

"uses its own crt to alloc memory for cstr" please do not use soo many abbreviations. The question could be much clearer

Though "123" is a bad example due to SSO. It should be longer to force a heap allocation...

If a() assigned str to a relatively long string (one that does not fit SSO), theoretically you can have a problem if both are linked statically to different runtime versions. But if it's the same version you should be OK.

While I have been able to dodge making DLLs (as well as .so) for my stuff so far, Microsoft seems to keep things fairly compatible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170

You are right each would use its own crt, but microsoft's crt does not do much as far as memory allocations go, at least modern versions don't. It pretty much delegates actual job to Windows' HeapAlloc/HeapFree. As such, there is still a single unified actual heap structure.

@wohlstad I thought CRT would have a memory pool. If same version should be OK. Do you mean CRT does not manage memory pool .  And can i always rely on this correct that same version should be OK.

@AndreyTurkin  Is there any possibility of Microsoft's CRT do much work on memory allocations infuture. Then above dll function call will cause mem corruption. And advised never to export such functions.

Everything is possible. Microsoft explicitly forbid doing what you do; it just happens to work, and very much not guaranteed to work.

@AndreyTurkin Thanks. Do you know the Microsoft page about this forbid or keywords to search. Just want to take a note.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries?view=msvc-170 "If your DLL passes CRT objects across the DLL boundary, or allocates memory that's freed outside the DLL, clients of the DLL must use the same copy of the CRT library as the DLL."
